# Query for compare several dates

Tags: sql

I need compare some dates, my query is getting 3 dates in first query =>
**2011-09-01,
2011-10-01,
2011-11-01**

And 3 dates in second query =>
**2011-07-01,
2011-11-01,
2011-08-01**

So How can I compare them and avoid this sql error?:

**"Subquery returned more than one value, which is not correct when it is following =,! =, <, <=,>,> = Or when used as an expression."**

Thanks

```
SELECT 
 c_Fk_IdBoleta as Numero_Boleta,
 'Pregunta (12)' as Numero_Pregunta,
 'El período transcurrido entre siembra y cosecha no corresponde al tipo de cultivo' as Detalle_Error
  FROM
    Clt_Sembrado as sembrado
  WHERE
     sembrado.c_Fk_IdBoleta = 45550711
    GROUP BY sembrado.c_Fk_IdBoleta, sembrado.d_MesAnioSiembra, sembrado.d_MesAnioCosecha, sembrado.si_Fk_IdDesglose
    HAVING 
   ( SELECT  sembrado.d_MesAnioCosecha 
   FROM Clt_Sembrado as sembrado, Clt_Desglose as desglose 
   WHERE sembrado.si_Fk_IdDesglose = desglose.si_Pk_IdDesglose 
   AND sembrado.c_Fk_IdBoleta = 45550711
   )                                                           >           (SELECT DATEADD(Month,6,sembrado.d_MesAnioSiembra)
                                                                            FROM Clt_Desglose as desglose, Clt_Sembrado as sembrado
                                                                            WHERE (((sembrado.si_Fk_IdDesglose = desglose.si_Pk_IdDesglose)AND
                                                                            (desglose.c_Fk_CodCiiu4 = 0112.00
                                                                            OR desglose.c_Fk_CodCiiu4 = 0111.01
                                                                            OR desglose.c_Fk_CodCiiu4 = 0111.02
                                                                            OR desglose.c_Fk_CodCiiu4 = 0113.01
                                                                            OR desglose.c_Fk_CodCiiu4 = 0113.03
                                                                            OR desglose.c_Fk_CodCiiu4 = 0113.05
                                                                            OR desglose.c_Fk_CodCiiu4 = 0113.06
                                                                            OR desglose.c_Fk_CodCiiu4 = 0113.07
                                                                            OR desglose.c_Fk_CodCiiu4 = 0113.08
                                                                            OR desglose.c_Fk_CodCiiu4 = 0113.10                            
                                                                            ))
                                                                            AND sembrado.c_Fk_IdBoleta = 45550711))
```

Here is the tables: The problem is one cultive could be inserted ONE or MORE times in the table Blt_Sembrado, and I need validate that the d_MesAnioCosecha is less (d_MesAnioSiembra + 6 months). FOR EACH CULTIVE INSERTED in the table Blt_Sembrado.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with compare the dates of the querys?, can you be more specific about what you want?

Comment: @Lamak Take a look at OP's comments in my answer. Further clarification is needed indeed...

Comment: And how does the table `Clt_Cultivo` relate with the table `Clt_Sembrado`?

Comment: -1 It is reasonable to expect that you mention the RDBMS and version you use - even without being asked. Also, "compare them" how exactly? It is rude to waste the time of people who would help you for free.

Comment: I think now is more clear if you don't understand, just tell me what specific please. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
AND sembrado.c_fk_idboleta = 40480711) > (SELECT ...
```

In order to make this work you have to ensure your sub-select will return at most one value.

If your date must be greater than all dates returned, then it's the same as being greater than the maximum date returned, thus using `MAX` will solve your problem:

```
AND sembrado.c_fk_idboleta = 40480711) > (SELECT 
   Dateadd(MONTH, 6, max(sembrado.d_mesaniosiembra))
...
```

Comment: Ok, but I need compare all of dates, one by one, for example: 2011-09-01 with 2011-07-01, 2011-11-01 with 2011-11-01, 2011-11-01 with 2011-08-01. Do you understand me?

Comment: Not really. Can you update your question with a simplification of your problem, instead of your actual data? This way we can better understand the concept behind instead of trying to understand your specific problem. Also, how about letting us know the RDBMS?

Comment: Please see my Update in question